# Can not write on ocpasswd

Tags: ubuntu-22.04, ocserv

Cannot write to '/etc/ocserv/ocpasswd'.

I get this Error when i want to create another account,
file '/etc/ocserv/ocpasswd' is locked.

How do i solve this Error?

Nothing, else try to edit ocpasswd via nano.

Comment: Have you tried to use `sudo`?

Comment: I tried, but i get again this Error file '/etc/ocserv/ocpasswd' is locked.